# gcc-4.2 failed with exit status 1

Tags: python, python-2.7, osx-lion, gcc-4.2

I've been looking for an answer to this issue but I couldn't find it, so here it is.

I'm trying to install [Uniconvertor](http://sk1project.org/modules.php?name=Products&product=uniconvertor) with a setup.py file into a MacOS X Lion (Python 2.7.2) using:

```
python setup.py install
```

Then I get the following error code:

```
running install
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
building 'uniconvertor.app.modules.streamfilter' extension
gcc-4.2 -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -O3 -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -DMAJOR_VERSION=1 -DMINOR_VERSION=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c src/modules/filter/streamfilter.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/src/modules/filter/streamfilter.o
unable to execute gcc-4.2: No such file or directory
error: command 'gcc-4.2' failed with exit status 1
```

I looked for the 'gcc-4.2' file in the Developer/usr/bin folder and it wasn't there, but there's a 'llvm-gcc.4.2' file that makes me think I should change the compiler from 'gcc-4.2' to the 'llvm-gcc.4.2' one.

I'm kind of new to Mac and I don't know how else to fix it.

Thanks.

Edit:

I tried using:

```
cd /Developer/usr/bin
ln -s llvm-gcc-4.2 gcc-4.2
```

And I get a little more progress, but then a new error:

```
running install_lib
creating /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/uniconvertor
error: could not create '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/uniconvertor': Permission denied
```

What could be the cause of this 'Permission denied'?

I'm running it into an Admin account and it doesn't ask for a password or anything.

Thank you again.

Comment: As of Xcode 4.2, Xcode no longer includes gcc-4.2.  Usually, llvm-gcc-4.2 or clang is a suitable substitute, but you might want to get in touch with the project's maintainers to ask why the build system explicitly requests gcc-4.2 instead of using the default system compiler.

Comment: See answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10238458/cant-install-orange-error-command-clang-failed-with-exit-status-1

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 28):

Try the following:

1. Install the latest Xcode.
2. From Xcode's Preferences menu, install the
   Command Line Tools (Downloads/Components tab).

Comment: This worked for me after upgrading to Lion and trying to install django-sentry. eventlet would not install dude to the error in the original question.

Comment: `xcode-select --install` does the same, as mentioned [in Brideau's answer above](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41751022/884640)

Answer (score 8):

I was able to resolve this by downloading one of these: https://github.com/kennethreitz/osx-gcc-installer/releases

Comment: Note that in newer versions of OS X, this is no longer the correct solution. As mentioned on the GitHub page, you should now just open a terminal and type `xcode-select --install`

Answer (score 5):

For newer versions of OS X (including macOS), you just need to open up a terminal and type:

```
xcode-select --install
```

Answer (score 3):

Try `sudo python setup.py install`.

Command line utilities will not ask you to escalate privileges and so must be run in `sudo` mode when the situation requires it (e.g., library installation into a global location).

Answer (score 2):

I tried @plusjeff answer, but Xcode 4.6 does not create a /Developer folder in the main directory anymore.

Therefore I sorted it out with a symlink:

```
sudo ln -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer /Developer
```

and it worked!

I have OSX 10.7.5 installed

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

I ran across this issue when installing a python library with pip.

After running `xcode-select --install`, I was still getting the issue.

So I created a symlink from "gcc" to "gcc-4.2" and that worked for me.

`ln -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/gcc /usr/local/bin/gcc-4.2`

`pip install --upgrade pip` did not help fix the issue for me.

The [answer by DanFreak](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15420215/1807627) didn't help me either, but it did give me the idea for what actually did work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error due to running an outdated version of pip. I ran `pip install --upgrade pip` and the error went away. Something to consider if you already have xcode command line tools installed and are still getting the error.

Answer (score 0):

You will need the Xcode installed.

Go to Xcode -> Preferences -> Locations and choose the Command Line Tools.