# Can't install Orange: "error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1"

Tags: python, macos, gcc, orange

I am trying to install [Orange](http://orange.biolab.si/) on my Mac OS X 10.7.3 (Lion) and I keep getting an error when using either pip or building from source. First, I was getting an error that read:

```
error: command 'gcc-4.0' failed with exit status 1
```

I have Xcode 4, which comes bundled with gcc 4.2.1. So I installed [64-bit/32-bit Python 2.7.3](http://www.python.org/download/), which has gcc 4.2 built in. I also tried to override the compiler choice using:

```
export CC=gcc-4.2
```

But this produced  a different error:

```
gcc-4.2 not found, using clang instead
...
error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1
```

Here is the full log:

```
$ python setup.py build
running build
running build_py
copying Orange/version.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/Orange
running build_ext
gcc-4.2 not found, using clang instead
building 'Orange.orange' extension
running pyxtract for Orange.orange
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python ../pyxtract/defvectors.py
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python ../pyxtract/pyprops.py -n orange
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python ../pyxtract/pyxtract.py -m -n orange lib_kernel.cpp lib_components.cpp lib_preprocess.cpp lib_learner.cpp lib_io.cpp lib_vectors.cpp cls_example.cpp cls_value.cpp cls_orange.cpp cls_misc.cpp functions.cpp orange.cpp
Parsing lib_kernel.cpp
Parsing lib_components.cpp
Parsing lib_preprocess.cpp
Parsing lib_learner.cpp
Parsing lib_io.cpp
Parsing lib_vectors.cpp
Parsing cls_example.cpp
Parsing cls_value.cpp
Parsing cls_orange.cpp
Parsing cls_misc.cpp
Parsing functions.cpp
Parsing orange.cpp
Warning: class 'PearsonCorrelation' will not be picklable
Warning: class 'ItemsetNodeProxy' will not be picklable
clang -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -O3 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -INone -Isource/include -Isource/orange/liblinear -Isource/orange/ppp -Isource/orange/px -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c source/orange/assoc.cpp -o build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/source/orange/assoc.o -fPIC -fpermissive -fno-common -w -DDARWIN -DORANGE_EXPORTS
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-fpermissive'
In file included from source/orange/assoc.cpp:25:
In file included from source/orange/random.hpp:26:
In file included from source/orange/root.hpp:25:
source/orange/garbage.hpp:221:9: error: use of undeclared identifier 'raiseError'
        raiseError("bad cast from %s to %s", typeid(U).name(), typeid(T).name());
        ^
source/orange/garbage.hpp:253:7: error: use of undeclared identifier 'raiseError'
      raiseError("Orange internal error: NULL pointer to '%s'", TYPENAME(typeid(T)));
      ^
source/orange/garbage.hpp:261:7: error: use of undeclared identifier 'raiseError'
      raiseError("Orange internal error: NULL pointer to '%s'", TYPENAME(typeid(T)));
      ^
source/orange/garbage.hpp:301:7: error: use of undeclared identifier 'raiseError'
      raiseError("Orange internal error: NULL pointer to '%s'", TYPENAME(typeid(T)));
      ^
source/orange/garbage.hpp:312:7: error: use of undeclared identifier 'raiseError'
      raiseError("Orange internal error: NULL pointer to '%s'", TYPENAME(typeid(T)));
      ^
In file included from source/orange/assoc.cpp:27:
source/orange/examplegen.hpp:143:38: error: expected member name or ';' after declaration specifiers
  TExampleIterator::TExampleIterator(const TExampleIterator &other);
  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^
source/orange/examplegen.hpp:143:38: error: expected ')'
source/orange/examplegen.hpp:143:37: note: to match this '('
  TExampleIterator::TExampleIterator(const TExampleIterator &other);
                                    ^
source/orange/assoc.cpp:33:1: error: explicit specialization of 'st_classDescription' after instantiation
DEFINE_TOrangeVector_classDescription(PAssociationRule, "TAssociationRules", true, ORANGE_API)
^
source/orange/orvector.hpp:105:57: note: expanded from macro 'DEFINE_TOrangeVector_classDescription'
    TClassDescription TOrangeVector< _TYPE, _WRAPPED >::st_classDescription = { _NAME, &typeid(TOrangeVector< _TYPE, _WRAPPED >), &TOrange::st_classDescription, TOrange_properties, TOrange_components };
                                                        ^
source/orange/ppp/assoc.ppp:111:72: note: implicit instantiation first required here
  {"rules", "association rules", &typeid(POrange), &TAssociationRules::st_classDescription, offsetof(TAssociationClassifier, rules), false, false, 0},
                                                                       ^
8 errors generated.
error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1
```

Comment: There's an error message right there - what's the problem?

Comment: The problem is that I can't install Orange because I keep getting the above error

Comment: I've had lots of buggy install experiences with Orange. Never seemed consistent to me. That's why I just use scikits.learn, scikits.image, scikits.timeseries, and scikits.statsmodels. Might be worth a look.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Problem solved: Xcode 4 doesn't actually come with gcc-4.2; it comes with the new LLVM compilers.

It was just a matter of doing:

```
export CC=llvm-gcc-4.2
export CXX=llvm-g++-4.2
```

then building Orange.

Answer (score 1):

From http://orange.biolab.si/forum/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=1568

```
export CC=gcc
export CXX=g++
pip install orange # for example
```

It seems more robust to not have to get into version number details if you don't have to, right? (I have not had to do this sort of thing before, so I don't know for sure.)

**Update**: The `pip install orange` example (above) currently [installs an older version of Orange (version 2.5a4 ) instead of 2.6](http://orange.biolab.si/forum/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=1705). To get the development version, use:

```
pip install -e hg+https://bitbucket.org/biolab/orange#egg=Orange
```

I got the above command from [here](http://orange.biolab.si/forum/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=1669&p=4758&hilit=pip#p4758).

Comment: Solved the same issue when trying to install 'matplotlib' using pip

Answer (score 1):

I had to do the following to fix the error on Mac OS Catalina. You can run it in the command line and also put into your `bash_profile`.

```
export CC=gcc
export CXX=clang
```