# Installing guppy with pip3 issues

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to install [guppy](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/guppy/). My program uses python3 so I must use pip3 exclusively. When I run:

```
pip3 install guppy
```

I get:

```
src/sets/sets.c:77:1: error: expected function body after function declarator
INITFUNC (void)
^
src/sets/sets.c:39:18: note: expanded from macro 'INITFUNC'
#define INITFUNC initsetsc
                 ^
1 error generated.
error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1
```

I tried doing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10238458/cant-install-orange-error-command-clang-failed-with-exit-status-1), even thourgh it wasn't the same and exported gcc and g++:

```
➜  ~ export CC=gcc
➜  ~ export CXX=g++
```

Running again:

```
src/sets/sets.c:77:1: error: expected function body after function declarator
INITFUNC (void)
^
src/sets/sets.c:39:18: note: expanded from macro 'INITFUNC'
#define INITFUNC initsetsc
                 ^
1 error generated.
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Most who had this issue used `sudo apt-get python-dev` or something of the like to resolve this issue, I couldn't find an equivalent for Mac. Is there a way to resolve this issue?

Comment: are you sure you have the headers? try to run `python3-config --include`

Comment: @mic4ael: I'm not really sure what headers you need, but when I run that I get: `-I/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/include/python3.5m -I/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/include/python3.5m`. Is it correct?

Comment: sorry I was thinking about python development headers

Comment: so far I can only say it is related with python 3 since it works perfectly fine when I try to install it for python 2.x

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Unfortunately it seems that `guppy` library works only for Python 2.x. An alternative could be [objgraph](http://mg.pov.lt/objgraph/)

Comment: I think I will leave this for a couple days to see if anyone can find a work around, otherwise I will accept. Main reason being: I heard that `guppy` was better than `objgraph` for detecting "memory leaks". But if I have to use `objgraph` I will. Thank you for the response.

Answer (score 7):

Try installing the [guppy3](https://pypi.org/project/guppy3/) fork of guppy that supports Python 3:

```
pip3 install guppy3
```

Comment: I'll try this later this week hopefully, so far it seems legitimate. +1 for now.