# How Can I Fix "expected declaration specifiers before ‘initsetsc’" When Installing Guppy (Python 3)?

Tags: python, guppy

EDIT: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38860927/1112524 Sorry

When I try to install [guppy/heapy](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/guppy/) for memory profiling,

```
pip3 install guppy --user
```

I get

```
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4

creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/src

creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/src/sets

x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -g -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I/usr/include/python3.4m -c src/sets/sets.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/src/sets/sets.o

src/sets/sets.c:76:1: warning: return type defaults to ‘int’ [-Wreturn-type]

 DL_EXPORT (void)

 ^

src/sets/sets.c: In function ‘DL_EXPORT’:

src/sets/sets.c:39:18: error: expected declaration specifiers before ‘initsetsc’

 #define INITFUNC initsetsc

                  ^

src/sets/sets.c:77:1: note: in expansion of macro ‘INITFUNC’

 INITFUNC (void)

 ^

src/sets/sets.c:108:1: error: expected ‘{’ at end of input

 }

 ^

src/sets/sets.c: At top level:

src/sets/sets.c:45:20: warning: ‘module_methods’ defined but not used [-Wunused-variable]

 static PyMethodDef module_methods[] =

                    ^

src/sets/sets.c:67:18: warning: ‘nysets_heapdefs’ defined but not used [-Wunused-variable]

 static NyHeapDef nysets_heapdefs[] = {

                  ^

src/sets/sets.c: In function ‘DL_EXPORT’:

src/sets/sets.c:108:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]

 }

 ^

error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

How can I fix this?

I tried installing things from this question, but it didn't work

[error: Setup script exited with error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26053982/error-setup-script-exited-with-error-command-x86-64-linux-gnu-gcc-failed-wit)

Also, just now I happened to try Python 2

```
pip install guppy --user
```

And it worked.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing guppy with pip3 issues](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38859593/installing-guppy-with-pip3-issues)

Comment: Yes, that's what my edit says. Found that right after posting.. didn't search hard enough at first. Too bad it won't work with 3.x