# Installing Zen Library

Tags: python, c, xcode, macos, zen

Attempting to install the Zen Network Library in python -- it is C based and uses xcode and cython to compile the C code. When I run the setup.py file to build the library i get this error:

unable to execute /: Permission denied
error: command '/' failed with exit status 1

Is the XCode not compiling this part of the package? How to proceed?

Comment: seems more like you do not have the Permission to write at a particular folder
could you provide the command you execute.
Or simply try to add `sudo` in front of it

Comment: the command is simply: "python setup.py install" in the directory where it exists. Will try with the sudo command. EDIT: tried, same result.

Comment: Since I do not have a mac I can't try it out on my own, but may be the problem is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8473066/gcc-4-2-failed-with-exit-status-1