# Error when trying to install PyCrypto

Tags: python, pip, pycrypto

I'm using Mac with latest OS X update. I've trying to install PyCrypto over Terminal but I'm getting error which is shown on image below. The command I used is `sudo pip install pycrypto`. Can you please help me with this issue? How do I resolve this? Thanks for your answers.

[image]

Here is the error:

```
macfive:Desktop admin$ sudo pip install pycrypto
The directory '/Users/admin/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/Users/admin/Library/Caches/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Collecting pycrypto
  Downloading pycrypto-2.6.1.tar.gz (446kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 450kB 2.4MB/s 
Installing collected packages: pycrypto
  Running setup.py install for pycrypto ... error
    Complete output from command /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/tmp/pip-build-CYttJL/pycrypto/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-mWAGUD-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py

.
.
.

src/hash_template.c:291: warning: return from incompatible pointer type
    src/hash_template.c: At top level:
    src/hash_template.c:306: error: initializer element is not constant
    src/hash_template.c:306: error: (near initialization for ‘ALG_functions[1].ml_name’)
    src/hash_template.c:306: error: initializer element is not constant
    src/hash_template.c:306: error: (near initialization for ‘ALG_functions[1].ml_meth’)
    fatal error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/lipo: can't figure out the architecture type of: /var/tmp//ccCeO0Zf.out
    error: command 'gcc-4.2' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/tmp/pip-build-CYttJL/pycrypto/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-mWAGUD-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-build-CYttJL/pycrypto/
```

Error is to big to copy it all. So I just copied the beginning and the end.

Comment: Please copy paste the error text instead of a screenshot.

Comment: I've updated my question and added error text.

Comment: you can download it from following link 
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pycrypto and try to install with python setup.py install. Use Readme file for more details.

Comment: I've tried that and it wont work. Getting the same error.

Comment: Although it's on linux, have you seen this: [gcc-4-2-failed-with-exit-status-1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8473066/gcc-4-2-failed-with-exit-status-1)?

Comment: Yes, thank you very much for this link. It lead me to the right solution. I had to run `export CC=gcc` and `export CXX=g++`. I've been using the clang compiler, not gcc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install the Python development files. I think it will work. Try

```
apt-get install autoconf g++ python2.7-dev
```

Or

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev
```

Either one of the above and then this below one

```
pip install pycrypto
```